# How to not trigger page refresh after revalidate path in next js 13

Tags: next.js

I'm using next 13.5.3.

I have a client component which has a server action, and in the server action I will revalidate the current url.

After revalidating the path, it seems like the page is refreshed, is there a way to not trigger page refresh after revalidating path?

I tried to use entirely client side query instead with react query and it works.